# Cannot upgrade my MacBook Air to macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, mac, software-update

I have a Macbook Air (Early 2015 model) with High Sierra on it. I want to upgrade it to the lastest macOS. When I go to the app store and hit the "download" button, it simply grays out and nothing happens. Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of Appstore with grayed download button.]

Please advise on how I can upgrade to the latest version. Thanks!

Comment: What model MacBook Air do you have? The earliest model of MacBook Air that supports macOS Catalina is the mid-2012 model as per [Apple’s macOS Catalina compatibly page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210222).

Comment: Macbook Air (Early 2015)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234175/os-x-el-capitan-download-button-is-grayed-out

Comment: @Madhubala The entire answer to that question is, “Just restarted the machine and that solved the issue. Now it's downloading.” So is that the solution? Maybe just upgrading to macOS 10.14 Mojave and then macOS 10.15 Catalina is the answer.

Comment: Another idea… Did you check your main “Applications” folder to see if macOS downloaded the installer in the background at some point? That might explain why it’s greyed out.

Comment: Check System Prefs > Software Update. That's where App Store ought to hand the task off to. Also check you are correctly signed into the Apple ID that owns the OS iteself & that you are logged into an admin account.